# iOS Google Cloud Messaging payload

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This is my first time doing everything around push notifications. I've implemented GCM with iOS and everything works. But my problem is I can't create good payload for my app. I'm using Postman to send push notifications. This is my content:

```
{       
  "registration_ids":["1234"],

  "data": {"aps":{"alert":"Hello, world!","sound":"default", "content-available":"1"}}
}
```

The problem is my userInfo gets dictionary for "aps":

[image]

How to properly send message. My userInfo does not have "content-available" as so, so my `(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler` is not called. How to properly test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. If you read through the [server documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref) you will see that you need to use the "Notification payload support" for this.

So your content should be something like

```
{
   "registration_ids" : ["1234"],
   "notification" : {
     "title" : "Hello, world!",
     "sound" : "default",
   },
   "content_available" : 1,
}
```